# FBConnect not working with iOS4?

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

I upgraded to iOS4 and noticed that -(void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid
is no longer invoked.

I have set the view controller as an FBSessionDelegate.

Has anyone come across this problem?

Comment: On investigating further, I found the error to be:
Error Domain=api.facebook.com Code=104 "Incorrect signature". Looks like there was a typo in the secret key :(

So all is well now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FBConnect worked well for me, the delegate method is called. The problem is somewhere else